# Whats best tools for testing web responsive?

Tags: testing, responsive-design

I have finish to develop any web responsive. One simple question from me : Whats the best tools that can trust for testing responsive web design because its impossible to check one by one every device :(.

Thank you

Comment: The best tool is to have a handful of people, that have never seen your site and let them browse through it. Not on your hardware, but their own. Afterwards, get their opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is in Firefox go to `Tools >> Web Developer >> Responsive Design View` and select dfiferent devices resolutions. Works for me.

But i think its available in Firefox 15 and later, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: how accurate if use web developer add on as you know ?

Comment: i always use this Firefox default Responsive design tool and i think its 95% accurate, clients never complained.

Answer (score 0):

1( You can ask a few people with either an Iphone, Ipad, Android phone or Nokia 3310 to test your new responsive website.

2( You can post a question on for example Facebook or Twitter for people to help you with your new design.

3( You can download an Emulator (Android or IOS) To test your website in so you can see how it looks on Android and Ios.

4( Resize your browser to less then the half of the screen to see your responsive design for your own. It always looks very similar on the phone. (Best browser for this is Google Chrome.

Comment: Its too many jobs that I doing !

Comment: The last option could also be done with Firefox as mentioned In the answer from @Kashif

Comment: how accurate if use web developer add on as you know ?

Comment: That plugin is almost 100% accurate. and when you're developing a responsive you always have a bit of space between the phone and tablet views. So it's almost 100% accurate.